# Angular 4 - Filter data using checkboxes

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

thank you in advanced for any replies, this problem has been unsolvable by me for a few days.

I have built a very simple Angular (5.2.8) application that display's data from a JSON file. I have used *ngFor to list the items and have created a pipe to allow the user to filter the data using a text input.

I now want to allow the user to filter the data using a collection of checkboxes. So far I have tried, IF statements and SWITCH statements but I am guessing that angular has a much more efficient way of allowing this to work.

I've looked in to (click) and ngModel but have had no luck so far creating a pipe that will allow this functionality.

If anyone can help me out I would be very grateful :)

**Pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'checkboxfilter'
})
export class CheckBoxFilter implements PipeTransform {

  transform(check: any, checked: any): any {
    console.log('checked',checked);
    return checked
            ? check.filter(club =>  club.location == checked) 
            : check;
  }

}
```

**HTML** - an example of a checkbox

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="button">
        <label>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Championship" [(ngModel)]="checked" name="club">
            <span>
                <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Championship
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

**HTML** - input of text filter and *ngFor

```
<input class="search" type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" placeholder="Search for a team name, location or league">
<div class="row">
  <div (click)="club.hide = !club.hide" class="card custom-card col-md-4 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let club of clubs | filter:term | checkboxfilter:checked">
```

**Switch Statement** - A previous attempted solution using a (click) event within the html

```
includeLeague(filter: string) {
      switch(filter) {
        case 'all':
        return this.clubs = this.clubs.filter(club => {
          return this.clubs;
        });         
        case 'championship':
        this.clubs = this.clubs.filter(club => {
          return club.league.toLowerCase().includes('championship');
        })
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is really vague. Can you provide code details showing what you have and are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, have added some code. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As pointed out in the angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe), you probably don't want to accomplish this task (filtering) with a pipe. This is because pipes are applied every change detection cycle, and filtering can be an expensive operation. Instead, manipulate the stored data directly. For example, here is some pseudo-code

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let datum of data"></div>

    <input type="checkbox"
           [value]="true"
           (change)="$event.value ? addFilter(hideRedData) : removeFilter(hideRedData)"
           >

    <input type="checkbox"
           [value]="true"
           (change)="$event.value ? addFilter(hideBlueData) : removeFilter(hideBlueData)"
           >
  `
})
class FakeComponent {
  private originalData: any[] = [];

  public data: any[] = [];

  private filters: ((data: any[]) => any[])[] = [];

  hideRedData() {
    this.data = this.data.filter(datum => !datum.red);
  }

  hideBlueData() {
    this.data = this.data.filter(datum => !datum.blue);
  }

  addFilter(filterFnc: () => any[]) {
    this.filters.push(filterFnc)
    this.filterData();
  }

  removeFilter(filterFnc: () => any[]) {
    this.filters = this.filters.filter(filter => filter !== filterFnc);
    this.filterData();
  }

  private filterData() {
    this.data = this.originalData.slice();

    this.filters.forEach(filter => filter());
  }
}
```

I'm not actually sure off the top of my head what the interface is for an input change event (so I'm not sure if `$event.value` is correct, etc), but hopefully you get the idea: when a checkbox change event fires, see if the checkbox is checked and add or remove the appropriate filtering function. Then filter the data again.